# IE and Firefox behaving differently when checkbox inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, checkbox, internet-explorer-11

I am working on creating a card component in react which has a  `<a>`
tag, `div` inside `<a>` tag(with some padding) and a `checkbox` inside
the `div`.

The below scenarios are to be fulfilled

- The div inside the  `<a>` tag should not be clickable so added `event.preventDefault()`
- The checkbox should be clickable and since its inside the `<a>` tag so `onChange` will not be triggered since its parent(div) is having
  `event.preventDefault()` so `onClick` gets triggered before `onChange`
  so I am doing `event.stopPropagation` in `onClick` event of checkbox

This solution works perfectly in chrome but is having issues when
running firefox and IE

Firefox behaviour

- The `<a>` tag works as expected
- The div is also not clickable
- The checkbox does trigger onChange but then it takes to the link given in the `href` of anchor tag, though `event.stopPropagation` has
  been given in `onClick` event

IE behaviour(I have tried in IE 11)

- The link doesn't work at all
- The div works as expected

When doing inspect element

- In chrome div occupies full width as expected
- In IE and Firefox, there is boundary covered by `<a>` tag and div also occupies the area inside that boundary

Here is the link to code https://codesandbox.io/s/0mp8z1p15v

I know wrapping up in div instead of `<a>` will fix everything but I am not able to figure out reason why its behaving differently in different browsers. And even after doing `event.stopPropagation` the link gets triggered.

Comment: You can’t have a checkbox inside a link; that’s invalid HTML. Knowing that it’s invalid and doing it anyway doesn’t really help.

Comment: @Ry I agree that checkbox shouldn't be inside link but sometimes we might have to do(as per design requirements) and it works perfectly in chrome so I am curious why its not working as expected in firefox and IE.

Comment: No, you never have to – because it doesn’t work. Design requirements don’t specify the exact markup you use. Rearrange it into a valid structure with the same behaviour. If you need help, make the question about that.